# Apple TrueTone alternative?

Tags: display, apple, color-management

Are there any alternatives to Apple’s TrueTone that works without a TrueTone sensor? (e.g. the ability to adjust the warmth of the display based on the color temperature of a room measured by a camera for example).

Comment: how is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Because I am asking if there’s alternative on Ubuntu? or if it’s possible to get truetone working on Ubuntu at all? Either through the original hardware or through software

Comment: Apple’s TrueTone is a set of **proprietary** sensors and **proprietary** software. Obviously there's nothing like that for other OSes.

Comment: @ChanganAuto your last comment should be an answer.  To close voters: It looks like a legitimate question.

Comment: @user68186 It's more like an absence of answer

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Hence why I asked about an alternative using **none proprietary** hardware and software.

to quote “the ability to adjust the warmth of the display based on the color temperature of a room measured by a camera for example“